# Add VM to Azure App Gateway python

Tags: python, azure-virtual-machine, azure-application-gateway

How do I add an existing VM to an existing App gateway via the Python SDK for Azure?

I've looked at [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/network-python-manage-application-gateway), and used it too, to create an app gateway programatically, but how do I go about adding newly created VMs to the existing gateway?

Answer (score 0):

You could check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42698609/how-to-create-azure-application-gateway-using-python-sdk).

Note: Firstly, your existing VM should be in your application gateway's VNet.

If you add your VM's public IP to application, you could use like below:

```
"backend_address_pools": [{
    "name": appgateway_backend_pool_name,
    "backend_addresses": [{
        "ip_address": "10.1.0.4"
    }, {
        "ip_address": "10.1.0.5"
    }]
}],
```

Check this [example](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/Walter-Shui/bf52aa8220cd5c74d4f98a1a8f8ef345/raw/c7b784be9b048125bf35eee51f2d7f3f69a81348/applicationgatey.py).

If you want to add VM's nic to application gateway, you need use like below:

```
"backend_address_pools": [{
    "name": appgateway_backend_pool_name,
    "backend_ip_configurations": [{
        "id": "/subscriptions/**********/resourceGroups/shuiapplication/providers/Microsoft.Network/networkInterfaces/shui361/ipConfigurations"
    }]
}],
```

Check Python SDK in this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure.mgmt.network.v2017_10_01.models.applicationgatewaybackendaddresspool?view=azure-python).

Comment: Sorry, where do I add the attribute?

While creating the NIC, or in the VM?

Comment: If you want to add VM's nic. Your VM and application gateway should be in the same VNet.

Comment: I understood that. I was actually asking where I add
"backend_address_pools": [{
        "name": appgateway_backend_pool_name,
        "backend_addresses": [{
            "ip_address": "10.0.0.4"
        }, {
            "ip_address": "10.0.0.5"
        }]
    }],

Comment: I know what you mean. I will test it in my lab.

Comment: I test in my lab, you need create a param contain this. https://imgur.com/a/dbEGs. I test in my lab, they are all required. Then using `network_client.application_gateways.create_or_update(rg,name,params_create)` update your application gateway.

Comment: I didn't understand what to replace in the template, sorry

Comment: Could you do this with Azure CLI 2.0. Python do this is very complex.

Comment: I have to do it using the Python SDK. What parameters are required if a VM is to be added?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164313/discussion-between-shengbao-shui-msft-and-varun-vembar).

Comment: I didn't understand how to add the newly created VM ID in the example you shared.

Comment: You need add VM's NIC id.

Comment: Sorry, where exactly do I add it?